# Launch ASP.NET Core Web-API programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi

How do I launch an ASP.NET Core Web-API programmatically from C#? The API should launch after I click on a button in a form.

I already added my API to my solution via `Add -> Existing Project...` but I don't know how to launch it from a different Project.

The Web-API is running on .NET Core 2.0 and I want to launch it from a project using .NET Framework 4

Comment: WebApi does not use documentation, so you can not add some reference as you can do with WCF or Webservices. So you need to write your own client ... https://www.google.be/search?q=generic+client+for+webapi

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for something like [this(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21)

```
dotnet run [-c|--configuration] [-f|--framework] [--force] [--launch-profile] [--no-build] [--no-dependencies]
[--no-launch-profile] [--no-restore] [-p|--project] [--runtime] [[--] [application arguments]]
```

dotnet run [-h|--help]

Comment: I thought there might be a more elegant way than running a cmd command. Especially when the API should also be shut down programmatically.

Comment: @Felix if you are using windows you can add this Web API to your IIS and start/stop it there. if not, I think there some similar way to do that with UNIX/Linux

Comment: All ASP.NET Core apps are essentially just console apps. Which means they're separate processes. You start the process just like you'd start *any* process, i.e. run it from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample project showcasing hosting of ASP.NET Core app in WPF: https://github.com/mkArtakMSFT/Samples/tree/master/WpfAspNetCore

Couple of things to pay attention to:

- The .NET Framework 4.6.1 is the minimum version which can host ASP.NET Core apps
- This sample is dummy and doesn't have much configuration (based off of empty ASP.NET Core Web app template content). You can, however, add reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package to add support for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to run the application as a [Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1), and start the service on click.