# How can I programmatically start and stop a .NetCore API Server project from another .Net project; in this instance, a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, api, orchestration

I have two projects in my Visual Studio solution; one is a .NET Framework console application and the other is a .NETCore API Server.

What I want is to be able to start and stop the server from the console.

- I know I can't just write the line for start up in my console application

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Because it would mean "add the server as a reference for the console app" and it wouldn't work because of incompatibility.

- I wanted to start the server from it's `.exe` file but it turns out that it's started from an IIS service who feed in the generated Release folder. So it seems that's not possible either.
- I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342919/create-a-websocket-server-in-net-core-console-application) from another question but it says that we can just create a self-hosted server in our console application.

I'm not sure that, architecturally speaking, it would be a good practice to make the whole server side of my project in a "Server.cs class". I imagined it would be better as a separate project that would be started from the main one.

---

So far I have a pseudo-result by starting both projects and making the server wait for a Tcpsocket message (to start or to quit) from the console, but that definitely doesn't feel right and isn't as stable as I want.

Does anyone have an idea of how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've found a way in [this answer to another question about launching programaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50797103/6224790).

Basically I need to compile my API project in a `.dll` and launch it later with the command

```
dotnet myServer.dll
```